# Porting an app from Java to Python

Tags: java, python, django, porting

I have written an RTMPS client a while back and needed it for my Django application but since Java and Python don't play well without using system calls (I don't want to use Jython) I wanted to rewrite the application in Python.

Would it work if I ported it as if to Python from Java? Of course we have to take into account the obvious things like multiple constructors have to be done differently in Python. Are there any other things that would not make it work in Python?

I am doing this because Java is so memory heavy and hoping that moving in into Python would reduce memory footprint and thus allow my web app to use it.

Comment: Your question is probably too general to get a good answer. Consider looking for tutorials or how-to guides to get you started. In the process, you may run into specific problems that can be answered on Stack Overflow. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest rewriting it completely but there are a lot of differences to take into account. Here's a starter for recognizing some of the common differences/mistakes: http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

Also if you are too lazy to rewrite the code (like me) there is an other option: [java2python](https://github.com/natural/java2python)